# Pulling 400 million rows using Spark SQL using Jupyter notebook

Tags: scala, azure-hdinsight, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and have been trying to execute a Spark SQL that has close to 400 million rows in the result set. I am executing the Spark SQL from Jupyter notebook. I am using Spark on Azure HDInsight. Following are the configurations of the Spark Cluster:

1. Number Of Cores per Executor - 3
2. Number of Executors - 5
3. Executor Memory - 4098 MB

As long as I execute the query to give me first couple of rows, everything works fine. But the moment I try to pull out all the rows i.e. 400 million rows, it throws an error that the "Executor has killed the request".

The first thing I would like to know is that is it possible to pull this volume of data from Spark SQL or Jupyter notebook.

If it is indeed possible to pull this volume, then what is it that I am doing incorrectly?

Currently, I dont have the exact error message, I will update this post with the error message shortly.

But it'll be a great help if anyone can help with this.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to handle 500 million rows with 4GB executors.Well... that is ambitious. You will be lucky to actually handle 10 million.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's against the idea of distributed computation to materialize 400M rows. If you can provide details of what you want to accomplish we can suggest how you accomplish that in parallelized manner. Spark has flexible APIs that can accommodate most of the use cases.

You can still make this happen. When you collect 400M rows you will accumulate them in the driver process. On Azure HDInsight, driver process runs in yarn master application. You will need to configure it to have enough memory to hold that much data. The configuration from Jupyter is:

%%configure -f
  { "driverMemory":"60G" }

Just add it as separate cell to the notebook.

Comment: we are trying Spark to determine whether it will fulfill our requirements. We need to build a solution which will enable our users to pull any column from the tables that the application uses and be able to display it into a data grid. Now, the users want to be able to pull N number of columns from across the tables, expecting all the rows of the table joins to be displayed in a data grid. This is the reason why I am trying to materialize 400M rows because that's the data volume that we could be looking at even in production.

Comment: In this case, if you need to provide scalable data exploration tool for the user you can either stretch spark driver to accommodate for the data sizes or you can store results in a temporary external store, like SQL or NoSQL database (MS SQL, MySQL, CosmosDB, HBase) and then just use adhock queries over it to show specific part of the data in the UI. In Spark it's easy to store results into external database in parallel using datasources.